# Why do I have 2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

So I'm trying to build a spring app with jsp, running with jetty, and it gives me a warning, then it fails because it's trying to run multiple WebApplicationInitializers.
I've tried everything that I have seen and I cannot find the problem.

Theres A LOT of warnings before the 2 WebApplicationInitializers detected:

```
[INFO] jetty-9.4.43.v20210629; built: 2021-06-30T11:07:22.254Z; git: 526006ecfa3af7f1a27ef3a288e2bef7ea9dd7e8; jvm 18.0.2.1+1-1
[WARNING] org.apache.taglibs.standard.Version scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/org/apache/taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl/1.2.5/taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/Version.class, jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/Version.class
[WARNING] org.apache.taglibs.standard.functions.Functions scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/org/apache/taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl/1.2.5/taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/functions/Functions.class, jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/functions/Functions.class
[WARNING] org.apache.taglibs.standard.resources.Resources scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/org/apache/taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl/1.2.5/taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/resources/Resources.class, jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/resources/Resources.class
[WARNING] org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.CatchTag scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/org/apache/taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl/1.2.5/taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/core/CatchTag.class, jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/core/CatchTag.class
[WARNING] org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ChooseTag scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/org/apache/taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl/1.2.5/taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/core/ChooseTag.class, jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/core/ChooseTag.class
[WARNING] org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.DeclareTag scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/org/apache/taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl/1.2.5/taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/core/DeclareTag.class, jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/core/DeclareTag.class
[WARNING] org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/org/apache/taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl/1.2.5/taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/core/ForEachSupport.class, jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/core/ForEachSupport.class
[WARNING] org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForTokensSupport scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/org/apache/taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl/1.2.5/taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/core/ForTokensSupport.class, jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/core/ForTokensSupport.class
[WARNING] org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ImportSupport$ImportResponseWrapper$1 scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/org/apache/taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl/1.2.5/taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/core/ImportSupport$ImportResponseWrapper$1.class, jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/core/ImportSupport$ImportResponseWrapper$1.class
[WARNING] org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ImportSupport$ImportResponseWrapper scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/org/apache/taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl/1.2.5/taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/core/ImportSupport$ImportResponseWrapper.class, jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/core/ImportSupport$ImportResponseWrapper.class
[WARNING] org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ImportSupport scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/org/apache/taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl/1.2.5/taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/core/ImportSupport.class, jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/core/ImportSupport.class
[WARNING] org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.NullAttributeException scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/org/apache/taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl/1.2.5/taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/core/NullAttributeException.class, jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/core/NullAttributeException.class
[WARNING] org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.OtherwiseTag scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/org/apache/taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl/1.2.5/taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/core/OtherwiseTag.class, jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/core/OtherwiseTag.class
[WARNING] org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.OutSupport scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/org/apache/taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl/1.2.5/taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/core/OutSupport.class, jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/core/OutSupport.class
[WARNING] org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ParamParent scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/org/apache/taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl/1.2.5/taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/core/ParamParent.class, jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/core/ParamParent.class
[WARNING] org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ParamSupport$ParamManager scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/org/apache/taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl/1.2.5/taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/core/ParamSupport$ParamManager.class, jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/core/ParamSupport$ParamManager.class
[WARNING] org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ParamSupport scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/org/apache/taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl/1.2.5/taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/core/ParamSupport.class, jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/core/ParamSupport.class
[WARNING] org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.RedirectSupport scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/org/apache/taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl/1.2.5/taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/core/RedirectSupport.class, jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/core/RedirectSupport.class
[WARNING] org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.RemoveTag scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/org/apache/taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl/1.2.5/taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/core/RemoveTag.class, jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/core/RemoveTag.class
[WARNING] org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.SetSupport scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/org/apache/taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl/1.2.5/taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/core/SetSupport.class, jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/core/SetSupport.class
[WARNING] org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.UrlSupport scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/org/apache/taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl/1.2.5/taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/core/UrlSupport.class, jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/core/UrlSupport.class
[WARNING] org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.Util scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/org/apache/taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl/1.2.5/taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/core/Util.class, jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/core/Util.class
[WARNING] org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.WhenTagSupport scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/org/apache/taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl/1.2.5/taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/core/WhenTagSupport.class, jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/core/WhenTagSupport.class
[WARNING] org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.fmt.BundleSupport scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/org/apache/taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl/1.2.5/taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/fmt/BundleSupport.class, jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/fmt/BundleSupport.class
[WARNING] org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.fmt.FormatDateSupport scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/org/apache/taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl/1.2.5/taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/fmt/FormatDateSupport.class, jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/fmt/FormatDateSupport.class
[WARNING] org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.fmt.FormatNumberSupport scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/org/apache/taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl/1.2.5/taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/fmt/FormatNumberSupport.class, jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/fmt/FormatNumberSupport.class
[WARNING] org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.fmt.MessageSupport scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/org/apache/taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl/1.2.5/taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/fmt/MessageSupport.class, jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/fmt/MessageSupport.class
[WARNING] org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.fmt.ParamSupport scanned from multiple locations: jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/org/apache/taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl/1.2.5/taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/fmt/ParamSupport.class, jar:file:///root/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar!/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/common/fmt/ParamSupport.class
```

(there's more but I can't post it all)

Then the final warning and error:

```
[INFO] Scanning elapsed time=143ms
[INFO] 2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
[WARNING] Failed startup of context o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@daf22f0{/,file:///mnt/target/webapp-tmp/,UNAVAILABLE}{file:///mnt/target/webapp-tmp/}
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration$JerseyWebApplicationInitializer does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void onStartup(javax.servlet.ServletContext)' of interface org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer.
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup (SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer.callStartup (ContainerInitializer.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart (ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext (ServletContextHandler.java:356)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp (WebAppContext.java:1449)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.startWebapp (JettyWebAppContext.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext (WebAppContext.java:1414)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart (ContextHandler.java:910)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart (ServletContextHandler.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart (WebAppContext.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart (JettyWebAppContext.java:397)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start (ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart (ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart (AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start (ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart (ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart (AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start (ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start (Server.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart (ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart (AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart (Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty (AbstractJettyMojo.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute (AbstractJettyMojo.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute (JettyRunMojo.java:150)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:298)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:577)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[INFO] Jetty server exiting.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.675 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-03-17T12:46:57Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.4.43.v20210629:run (default-cli) on project demo2: Failure: Failed to bind to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8080: Address already in use -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.hatoku</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>demo2</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.4.43.v20210629</version>
                <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>3</scanIntervalSeconds>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I tried mostly deleting dependencies that could be a problem, but it still gives me the same problem anyways.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the versions of JDK(17) and spring boot(3.0.4) are not compatible with versions of spring(4.3.9.RELEAS) and jetty(9.4.43.v20210629) in your pom.xml.

You may adjust spring version to `5.3.26` and jetty version to `11.0.14`, and have a try.

I am not sure if it works, basically you need to make jetty, spring, jdk version compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, it might be useful to someone: in my case I had a properties file (application.properties) that should be in a certain tomcat subdirectory. When I migrated from 8.5 to tomcat 10 I forgot to copy this directory and this was the error I got "2 WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath".

I could only find out by looking closely at all the tomcat log files, \apache-tomcat-10.1.13\logs in my case.